# ngrok and docker, failed to complete tunnel connection

Tags: docker, ngrok

i've changed nothing within my setup and ngrok seems to have stopped working for me.

Running `ngrok http -host-header=rewrite launch.localhost:80` would usually work just fine.

This is my error:

```
The connection to http://d678207f86ae.ngrok.io was successfully tunneled to your ngrok client, but the client failed to establish a connection to the local address launch.localhost:80.

Make sure that a web service is running on launch.localhost:80 and that it is a valid address.

The error encountered was: dial tcp: lookup launch.localhost: no such host
```

If I navigate to `launch.localhost` the docker server is running just fine.

Not too sure what kind of other information you'd need to help?

Answer (score 0):

For me, it was never running before, but I was getting the same error for

```
ngrok http -host-header=rewrite launch.local:80
```

It helped when I changed it to

```
ngrok http -host-header=launch.local 80
```